# why is this django regex wont work?

Tags: python, regex, django

I have this regex in my urls.py for my blog app and I'd like to know why is it not working.

```
url(r'^/tag/(?P<tag_text>\w+)/$', views.tag, name='tag'),
```

and I have defined this in the blog's views.py

```
def tag(request,tag_text):
```

and this in the application's urls.py

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

I have tried 
localhost/blog/tag/sport
but I still get: The current URL, blog/tag/sport, didn't match any of these.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you not supposed to have something after /sport , for the \w+ you wrote on the regex ?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza the ```\w+``` is supossed to match the tag name (in this case ```sport```). Anyway, on topic: I think your pattern is trying to match an extra ```/```. You have a trailing ```/``` before your include, and a leading ```/``` in the ```tag``` url; try removing one of those.

Comment: @asermax Thanks! yea the extra slash was the problem.

Comment: didn't think it deserved to be an answer, but if you don't mind i'm going to write it down for future reference d:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is trying to match an extra `/`, since your include url requires a trailing slash, and your `tag` url is trying to match a leading slash.

You should remove either one to make it work:

```
# tag url in blog/urls.py
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_text>\w+)/$', views.tag, name='tag'),

# include in project/urls.py
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```